# Error while posting data to server using retrofit

Tags: android, retrofit

i am trying to send data from my app to server using retrofit. I am sending data in json format to the interface. This webservice works with postman but when used in application gives following error

```
com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was STRING at line 2 column 1 path $
```

While debugging i can see that my data is in proper json format as below

```
{
"login_id":39,
"contact_no":"91775668"}
```

Here is my method for sending data to server

```
  JSONObject object=new JSONObject();
    try {

        object.put("login_id",loginID);
        object.put("contact_no",mobileNumber);

        Call<OTPResponse>call=userService.getOTP(key,object.toString());
        call.enqueue(new Callback<OTPResponse>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<OTPResponse> call, Response<OTPResponse> response) {

                }else {


                }
```

And my POST method from interface

```
    @Headers("Content-Type:application/json")
    @POST(OTP_URL)
    Call<OTPResponse>getOTP(@Header("API-KEY")String key,@Body String otpdetails);


OTPResponse.java


public class OTPResponse {


    @Expose
    @SerializedName("message")
    private String message;
    @Expose
    @SerializedName("OTP")
    private String OTP;
    @Expose
    @SerializedName("status")
    private boolean status;

    public String getMessage() {
        return message;
    }

    public void setMessage(String message) {
        this.message = message;
    }

    public String getOTP() {
        return OTP;
    }

    public void setOTP(String OTP) {
        this.OTP = OTP;
    }

    public boolean getStatus() {
        return status;
    }

    public void setStatus(boolean status) {
        this.status = status;
    }
}
```

response from the server

```
    {
    "status": true,
    "OTP": "422733",
    "message": "OTP sent successfully."
}
```

Comment: looks like your response is not matching as expected. app is expecting an object where api might be returning array. post your OTPResponse and response json.

Comment: OTPResponse and response json is added.Please  check

Comment: Where are you getting this Exception

Comment: can you check what is value of `object.toString()` as it looks like you are sending only string not json as expected.

Comment: public void onFailure() in call.enqueue

Comment: {
"login_id":39,
"contact_no":"91775668"} this is value of object.toString() @karan Mer

Comment: I would let Retrofit to form a JOSN for me. You should pass the login_id and contact number directly to the Retrofit interface as body.

Comment: Does your API accepts `FormUrl` data for **request params**?

Comment: Please post logcat, what response u are getting back, seems like you are getting some error back from backend instead of 200 OK

Answer (score 0):

**Solution:**

Instead of Writing string in the `@Body`:

```
Call<OTPResponse>getOTP(@Header("API-KEY")String key,@Body String otpdetails);
```

Use this:

```
Call<OTPResponse>getOTP(@Header("API-KEY")String key,@Body JsonObject otpdetails);
```

and your method call must be:

```
Call<OTPResponse>call=userService.getOTP(key, object);
```

Instead of:

```
Call<OTPResponse>call=userService.getOTP(key,object.toString());
```

Hope it helps.

**UPDATE:** As **NIKHIL** has mentioned, try adding `@FormUrlEncoded` to solve `Internal server error`. So, the updated code should be:

```
@FormUrlEncoded
@POST(OTP_URL)
Call<OTPResponse>getOTP(@Header("API-KEY")String key, @Body JsonObject otpdetails);
```

Try Now.

Comment: Please see my **UPDATE** in Solution and try.

Answer (score 0):

you need to chagne your api call with below code.

```
public class PostData {

private String id;
private String phone;

public PostData(String id, String phone) {
    this.id= id;
    this.phone = phone;
}

public String getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(String id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public String getPhone() {
    return phone;
}
public void setPhone(String phone) {
    this.phone= phone;
}

}
```

Interface method

```
@Headers("Content-Type:application/json")
@POST(OTP_URL)
Call<OTPResponse>getOTP(@Header("API-KEY")String key,
@Body PostData body);
```

and change your request as below

```
 JSONObject object=new JSONObject();
 try {

    Call<OTPResponse>call=userService.getOTP(key,new PostData(email,password));
    call.enqueue(new Callback<OTPResponse>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<OTPResponse> call, Response<OTPResponse> response) {
        } else { }
```

Comment: if `<String, Object>` doesn't work try `<String, String>` for map

Comment: i used both the approaches still gives the same error

Comment: com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was STRING at line 2 column 1 path $

Comment: @NewBee: if you are using gson with your project try the updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

Do this

```
Call<OTPResponse>getOTP(@Header("API-KEY")String key,@Body("login_id") String loginId, @Body("contact_no") String contactNo);
```

you can pass integers instead of string if you want.

Additionally I think you would also need `@FormUrlEncoded` for a POST request.

```
@FormUrlEncoded
@POST(OTP_URL)
Call<OTPResponse>getOTP(@Header("API-KEY")String key,@Body("login_id") String loginId, @Body("contact_no") String contactNo);
```

**EDIT:** `@FormUrlEncoded` instead of `@URLFormEncoded`.

Comment: It gives the error Error:(47, 64) error: cannot find symbol method value()

Answer (score 0):

In this line you are converting your json in string.Please change your getOtp() function  2nd parameter in json and user

```
Call<OTPResponse>call=userService.getOTP(key,object);
```

not

`Call<OTPResponse>call=userService.getOTP(key,object.toString());`

Comment: That means bug in your server side